# flutter dio or http doesn't work on some emulators in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, http, dio

I cloned my code on different PCs. It works on some of them and doesn't work on the others.
I have a login screen with a mobile number. when I send a request nothing happens and it doesn't give any responses. but that exact same code works fine on other pc and send verification code. I don't know what is the difference that makes it not work on my pc.

```
Future<Response> init(String mobile) async {
  Response response;
  try {
    response = await Dio()
        .post(URLs.BASE_URL + URLs.INIT, data: InitModel(mobile: mobile));
  } on DioError catch (e) {}
  return response;
}
```

and here I call it:

```
 void onPressed() {
    var text = tEC?.text?.trim();
    init("0$text").then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ConfirmCode(
              mobileNum: tEC.text,
              message: response.data['message'],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: 'works on some of them and doesn't work on the others' that mean the problem in environment, what is the result of (flutter doctor) In the devices that the project did not work on? After that if you pass doctor successfully what is the error when you try to run the project?

Comment: @AnasSafi  No issues found on flutter doctor. and it doesn't return any errors. it just stuck on dio.post.

Comment: Are you using localhost or public server in (URLs.BASE_URL)?

Comment: @AnasSafi public server

Comment: Please run project by debugging mode you will see the error, or print error in "on DioError catch (e) { // print e here }"

Comment: @AnasSafi it doesn't go to catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was because of the emulator's proxy setting. I change it from "android studio proxy setting" to "no proxy".